# How to get a JWT token when not logged in

Tags: authentication-authorization

If I am logged in (have a session cookie) and make a GET request to `/jwt/token`, then I get a JWT token.  How do I get the token if I am not logged in?

[This article by Preston So](https://preston.so/writing/decoupled-drupal-authentication-with-json-web-tokens/) states:

> As a logged-in user, **or when you issue a GET request against
> /jwt/token with credentials of a user with the appropriate
> permissions,** you will receive a token like that seen below, with which
> we can issue authenticated requests to Drupal.

So this is what I tried in Postman:

- GET: `example.com/jwt/token`
- Headers: `Content-Type`: `application/json`
- Body: raw: `{"name": "myUsername", "pass: "password"}`

This resulted in an "access denied" message.

I also tried using `form-data` and `x-www-form-urlencoded` for the Body, but those didn't work either.

I know JWT is configured correctly because if I log in first in Postman (get a session cookie) and then try the request, it gives me the token.

So what can I use in Postman to get the token from `/jwt/token` when I'm not already logged in? (How do I provide my login info to Postman?)

Comment: `basic_auth` is mentioned in the route for /jwt/token, maybe try `username:password@example.com/jwt/token`. The body is usually ignored for GET requests so it makes sense that what you tried didn't work